# Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet was not available. SQL Server PowerShell components may not be installed

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2016

I am getting the exception as mentioned when I am trying to execute sql queries using PowerShell

`[ERROR] Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet was not available.
SQL Server PowerShell components may not be installed.`

The weird thing I figured out was with this path `$env:PSMODULEPATH`. I am having the paths set as follows

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\`

Instead of the above if I just move the following path before `SQL Server` or to the first position it is working fine
`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\`

When I update this is how it looks

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\`

So is there any way to move it to the first place or above to the SQL PS module path

Comment: so what's the problem, you are looking for a guidance how to set environment variable?

Comment: Is there is any possibility to over come this

Answer (score 0):

NOw you just need to set the environmental variable to point to that path externally:

```
Set-Item -Path env:psmodulepath -Value "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;"
```

This should do our job.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so how setting this variable to the exact same value it is now should help?

Comment: But if there are any apart from these 3 it will completely over ride all

Comment: Then you do one thing, Simply take the current value by using `Get-Item env:$x` and then add the path with the new value. Thats it.. :)
Hope you understand what I meant. Else I will give the script. But give me sometime then. Just try. Its pretty simple logic